# Mosquitto server hosted on Digital ocean not making remote connections with android and Eclipse Paho Javascript Clients

Tags: mqtt, digital-ocean, remote-access, remote-server, mosquitto

I hosted Mosquitto MQTT broker on Ubuntu in Digital Ocean Cloud droplet. It's domain name is instrux.live and IP of the domain is 192.34.63.138. I publish and subscribe messages from two terminal windows and it worked fine.

When I tried to connect it with the android using Paho MQTT android client it could not connect. I also checked its connection with the MyMQTT android application and it did not connect. After making sure the android code has not any error, I again checked its connection with the Eclipse Paho Javascript client on eclipse.org website and it did not connect. Now, I have realized there might be something missing or wrong in my broker configuration which is not allowing it to get connected with other clients remotely. I have also opened firewall for ports 1883 for Android client and 8083 for the Javascript client and still it is not connecting.Here is mosquitto configuration file:

```
allow_anonymous true
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd


listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8083
protocol websockets
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is "Connection Refused" rather than a timeout I suspect that you have not configured the firewall to allow inbound traffic on port 8083.

You may need to do this both on the machine it's self and in  Digital Ocean's console.

Comment: The error is connect timeout.I have configured the firewall to allow inbound traffic port on 8083 and 1883 : both on the machine and in Digital Ocean's console. Still it is giving the same error.

Comment: And you are 100% sure that mosquitto is using the config file you listed? The logs will list what ports it's listening on (you can also use `lsof -i` to see which ports it's bound to on what interfaces.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I would like to take this opportunity to express my gratitude for your kind guidance.